# Get data where comparing two different table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a feature which the post are require approve by 5 admin in order to display. When a post is created, the post will store in Posts table. The post by default the approved column is false. In order to display the post , it require 3 approval out of 5 admin. So i want get the post from database and show in admin panel. Each time will randomly show 1 post for the admin. If admin approved the post.The approval is storing in other table name Approvals.

The model is

Post model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum\Post');
}
```

In approval model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'admin_id',
    'post_id',
    'approved'
];
public function admin(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
}

public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum\Post');
}
```

In my controller i am using this to get random unapproved post. But now i need to filter out the post, if approval table are contain the approval data by one of the admin. He/she will not see the post again.

```
$post = Post::inRandomOrder()->where('approved', false)->first();
```

In case of it might having many post to approve. How can i know that the admin is approved the post so the same post will not showing again to the same admin.

Comment: Why is the `post()` relationship in your Post model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post()` relationship in your `Post` model seems like a bug.  I think it should be a relationship with your `Approval` model, right?  So first, in your Post model, replace the `post()` method with:

```
public function approvals() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\Approval');
}
```

Then, here's one approach for your query:

```
$post = Post::inRandomOrder()->where('approved', false)
->with('approvals')
->get()
->filter(function($value, $key) {

    // A post without any approvals yet is OK
    if ($value->approvals->count() === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // If it has approvals, check the current admin isn't one of them
    return !$value->approvals->contains('admin_id', \Auth::user()->id);
})
->first()
```

Comment: Its working, seem like complicated if not well understanding the relationship. Thanks a lot